# How to uninstall a plugin in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [uninstall plugins in Eclipse 3.4.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369889/uninstall-plugins-in-eclipse-3-4-x)

How to uninstall a plugin in eclipse?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of the question in the link below:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369889/uninstall-plugins-in-eclipse-3-4-x)

**Help->About Eclipse->Installation Details** select the plug-in to un-install..

Answer (score 5):

Click Help > About and then click Installation Details

Select the Plugin you installed and then click uninstall

Thats all

Its uninstalled

Answer (score 1):

"Help" -> "About Eclipse" -> "Installation Details" -> (select a plugin)"**Uninstall**"

Answer (score 1):

Use the menu option: **Help > About**, then **Installation Details**

Find the desired Plugin click **uninstall**

Restart your workspace and run it using the clean flag: `eclipse.exe -clean`

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> (select a plugin)

Then 
Uninstall

Answer (score 1):

Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> (select a plugin)

Then Uninstall