# Correct way to remove plugin from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Last times, I'm facing problem of removing plugins from Eclipse.

symptoms:

**1.** if removing thru *already installed* menu,that can't reinstall correctly and have several perspectives - e.g. for SQL Explorer. (in `Open Perspective` menu)

**2.** if removing thru file system - manually from `plugins` directory,that I'm not certain about what .jars should I remove

The question is, what are the steps that guarantee **correct full** removing of plugin and what is better, manual or automatic removing?

Share,please,your experience.

Comment: I have the same problem trying to uninstall **Eclipse SQL Explorer**.  It is not listed as a plugin under **Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Installed Software Tab**.  I had installed it via **Help > Install New Software**.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall plugins in Eclipse 3.4.X or higher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369889/how-to-uninstall-plugins-in-eclipse-3-4-x-or-higher)

Comment: hi @GeroldBroser, I can't answer you definitey due using Intelij IDEA more than 5 years already)

Comment: @sergionni It's just the automated msg if one marks a Q as duplicate, Which I did. Sorry for disturbing you unintentionally. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would like to propose my solution,that worked for me.

It's reverting Eclipse and its plugins versions, to the version just before the plugin was installed.

Comment: That should certainly work too - and can/should be used when you make a major update and fail. But Sandmans solution is the correct one for just a single feature...

Comment: Thanks. Luckily I didn't remove the older Eclipse. Don't understand the downvotes on this answer though.

Comment: please provide the steps, otherwise how do others know how to revert back?

Comment: You should consider accepting the *real* answer, while keeping this as a side one

Answer (score 295):

Using the menus, open

- **Help | About Eclipse IDE | Installation details** (in newer versions),
- **Help | Installation Details** (in older versions), or
- **Help | About Eclipse | Installation details** (in even older versions).

In the "Installed software" tab click on the software that you wish to uninstall, then click the "Uninstall..." button below.

If you installed the plug-in by dropping into the `dropins` folder, then just delete it from the `dropins` folder and restart Eclipse.

See the answer of @Cogentleman for more recent versions of Eclipse.

Comment: This won't work for all plugins... Subclipse refuses to be removed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6070424/how-to-fully-delete-subclipse-plugin

Comment: I believe that you can only remove plugins with this method if they did NOT come pre-installed in your original distribution.

Comment: On latest eclipse versions there shortcut: Help->Installation details.
No need to go to "About Eclipse" dialog.

Comment: I follow your steps but it did not showing me uninstall option, what should I do?

Comment: This didn't work for me because I had dropped the jar in the plugins folder manually. There were no menu options to uninstall it, so I had to delete the file manually.

Comment: In Eclipse Oxygen, they've reverted back to the old way (Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details).

Comment: The following related question and answer may also be useful: how to remove unused jars of uninstalled plugins, or old versions of plugins after an update, ["How to remove old versions of Eclipse plugins?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52577085/4116988).

Comment: This still works out of the box on Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0), thanks.

Comment: @marcolopes You're (still) right (after all that years). See [my answer herein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753682/1744774).

Comment: @Mark You're (still) right (after all that years). See [my answer herein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753682/1744774).

Answer (score 13):

Eclipse Photon user here, found it under the toolbar's Windows > Preferences > Install/Update > "Uninstall or update" link > Click stuff and hit the "Uninstall" button.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't know why this needs to be different for every.single.version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

- **For Windows:**
  Go to ***Help** > **About Eclipse** > **Installation Details*** , select the software you no longer want, and click **Uninstall**.
- **On Mac:**
  Go to ***Eclipse** > **About Eclipse** > **Installation Details.***
- **In older versions:** You might need go to ***Help > Software Updates > Manage Configuration***. Select the plugin to Uninstall, and disable it with the task shown in the right window.

**There are few things to keep in mind:**

- '**Uninstalling**' a feature, using the steps above, disable the feature or plug-in.
- They are **still available** on disk, and they can be enabled at any time in the future.
- **Completely removing a Plugin** from the system requires a manual process that should be done when Eclipse is not running.
- In order to do this, If you are removing a **feature** you will have to manually remove the files there associated with the feature from the ***eclipse/features*** directory and its plug-ins from the ***eclipse/plugins*** directory.
- If you are removing a **plugin** you will have to manually remove the files there associated with the plugin from the ***eclipse/plugins*** directory.

**From the [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F#:%7E:text=Run%20Help%20%3E%20About%20Eclipse%20%3E%20Installation,longer%20want%20and%20click%20Uninstall.) of Eclipse:**

> Be very cautious as to which files you delete, and always have a backup of your Eclipse directory. If you remove the wrong files from these directories, you may have quite some trouble restoring your Eclipse to a stable state. Therefore, unless your hard disk storage capacity is extraordinarily limited, it is recommended that you simply leave the physical files in place.
>
> - Note that when manually removing plugins as described above, it is likely that some metadata will still cached by Eclipse. This can lead to problems later on. Running Eclipse with the -clean option may help with that, as it causes Eclipse to clean the cached metadata. See the Running Eclipse help page for details about this option.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Eclipse Kepler release.  There is no Installation Details or About Eclipse menu item under help.  For me, it was Help | Eclipse Marketplace...

I had to click on the "Installed" tab. The plug-in I wanted to remove was listed there, with an "Uninstall" option.

Answer (score 3):

Correct way to remove install plug-in from Eclipse/STS :

Go to install folder of eclipse ----> plugin --> select required plugin and remove it.

**Step 1**

```
E:\springsource\sts-3.4.0.RELEASE\plugins
```

**Step 2**

```
select and remove related plugins jars.
```

Comment: That is not the correct way. It might work, but is not the way you are supposed to do it since Eclipse manages its plugins.

Comment: @thoni56 And yet it's still the only way for features/plugins that ship with an Eclipse variant. So, it's not Tayfun to blame, it's Eclipse.org.

Comment: However, removing the JARs completely isn't the best decision. It's better to [just move them to another dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68753682/1744774).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by [sergionni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469192/978502)'s answer, I ended up doing the following steps:

`Help --> Installation Details --> Installation History tab`

In the `Previous configurations` table, you can select a `configuration` and see in the `Configuration contents` exactly which plugins were installed and are included in it.

It's easy to find the configuration that contains the plugin you want to remove, using the `Compare` button. This button is enabled when two configurations are selected.

After tracking the configuration that's responsible for that plugin, select the previous configuration and press the `Revert` button.

Note that if you revert to a configuration that isn't the one just right before the `Current Installation`, it causes any other plugins that were installed since, to be uninstalled as well.

Comment: Might help or not. I have 2 _Previous configurations_ there (it's an installation a few weeks old) → Compare → "_There are no differences between the selected inputs._"

Answer (score 2):

Help --> About Eclipse --> Installation Details --> select whatever you want to uninstall from "Installed Software" tab.

Answer (score 2):

While *Help* → *About Eclipse IDE* [or wherever it was in the past or will be in the future] → <kbd>Installation Details</kbd> → *Installed Software* → <kbd>Uninstall...</kbd> is the official and preferred way there are features/plugins the latter button of which is disabled.

Remember also that there aren't only *plugins* but *features* too. In my case I wanted to remove *Mylyn* and *Wild Web Developer* from a rather fresh *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers* package. I did the following.

But first a:

| DISCLAIMER |
| --- |
| Enter ECLIPSE_HOME at your own risk. Mistakes like typos might be in the following, too. I take *no responsibility* for whatsoever. |

- Created the directories `features.DISABLED` and `plugins.DISABLED` in Eclipse's home dir.
- Moved `*mylyn*` from `ECLIPSE_HOME/features` to `ECLIPSE_HOME/features.DISABLED`
- Moved `*wildwebdeveloper*` from `ECLIPSE_HOME/features` to `ECLIPSE_HOME/features.DISABLED`
- Moved `*mylyn*` from `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins` to `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins.DISABLED`
- Moved `*wildwebdeveloper*` from `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins` to `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins.DISABLED`

After starting Eclipse there were about a dozen "*not found*" errors in Eclipse's *Error Log* view. If you double-click on each of them you can see which dependency plugin JAR(s) haven't been found.

- Set the  *Error Log* view's filter to just display errors and warnings.
- Moved the dependency plugin `*.jar`s mentioned in the errors from `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins.DISABLED` back to `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins` one by one (with Eclipse restart after each) until no "*not found*" error appeared in the view any longer. It were  nine `*mylyn*.jar`s in the end.:

```
*.mylyn.commons.core_*
*.mylyn.commons.net_*
*.mylyn.commons.notifications.core_*
*.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui_*
*.mylyn.commons.screenshots.ui_*
*.mylyn.commons.ui_*
*.mylyn.commons.workbench_*
*.mylyn.commons.wikitext.markdown_*
*.mylyn.commons.wikitext.*
```

Note that this applies to a rather fresh *Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0)* installation. It might be different from one – even patch – version to the other.

Furthermore:

- Keep Eclipse's *Error Log* view open for a while. The underlying OSGi activates bundles (plugins) on the fly if they are referenced from an other bundle (plugin) for the first time. And if one isn't there then...
- Check the *Error Log* view especially after installing new features/plugins. They might rely on plugins/JARs you moved to `.DISABLED`. If that's the case move the according JAR(s) back to `ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins` and/or `ECLIPSE_HOME/features`.
- If something doesn't work as it did in the past once in the future remember what you did and ... → *Error Log* view.

Answer (score 1):

For some 'Eclipse Marketplace' plugins Uninstall may not work.
(Ex: SonarLint v5)

So Try,

```
Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation details
```

- search the plugin name in 'Installed Software'
- Select plugin name and Uninstall it

**Additional Detail**

To fix plugin errors, after the uninstall revert back  older version of plugin,

```
Help -> install new software..
```

- Get plugin url from Google search and Add it
    (Example: https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org)
- Select and install older versions of the Plugin. 
   This will fix most of  the plugin problems.