# Is there some way to uninstall plugins for Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Every question dealing with uninstalling/disabling plugins for Eclipse Juno mentions an Uninstall button but I simply can't find it and Eclipse's help for Juno is sadly no help.

Has this ability been eliminated or omitted or is it in some place different for Juno?

Comment: exact duplicate of [Correct way to remove plugin from Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174725/correct-way-to-remove-plugin-from-eclipse)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Uninstall...` button is available from the `About Eclipse` dialog. From that dialog click `Installation Details` and it's under the `Installed Software` tab. This typically is only available for features, not plugins. If you can find the appropriate feature that contains the plugins you want to eliminate, that should do the trick for you.

If you are unsure of the feature containing the plugin, you can attempt to go the `Installation History` tab in the `Installation Details` window and try to `Revert` to a previous version of Eclipse that didn't have the plugins.

Finally, you can always manually go into your Eclipse installation folder under the `plugins` directory and remove them manually. This will sometimes require that you run `eclipse -clean` from your command line/terminal to truly get rid of the plugin. This is probably the most error prone approach as you could cause problems with features/plugins that may depend on the removed plugins.

Comment: Just a note, this was where it was located on Eclipse 4.2.1 (Juno). If you're on a Mac, `About Eclipse` is under the main `Eclipse` menu, otherwise I believe it's normally under the `Help` menu.

Comment: Thanks, Marc. The History/Revert is something I also didn't know about.