# Pydev Perspective Not Showing After Install For Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

After installing the latest version of Pydev on eclipse it is not showing under the list of available perspectives.

Eclipse does however list pydev as being installed which seems weird to me. I would also like to add that I installed pydev through the standard method (Through the "install new software" option under help).

Any help on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update : we need java8 now for pydev to show up in eclipse after installation  (http://www.pydev.org/download.html#pydev-does-not-appear-after-install)

Comment: I just successfully installed PyDev 5.7.0 from the marketplace of
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
with Java jdk1.8.0_131 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 ... 

AND

PyDev is not showing up in preferences.

Comment: Seems to have been fixed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I spent hours trying to get PyDev 3.0.0 plugin working with Eclipse Kepler on my mac. I tried

1. Marketplace installation
2. Install Software through Update Site
3. Dropping plugin files under eclipse/dropins

Nothing worked until I finally tried version 2.8.2 of the plugin. I would say get a zip of 2.8.2 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/pydev/PyDev%202.8.2/PyDev%202.8.2.zip/download) and put the unzippied version in your /dropins folder of Eclipse. Restart Eclipse. Then go to the preference menu and notice PyDev entry should be there. Sometime it is better to start the Eclipse with admin credentials. Something like this on command line:

```
sudo /Users/username/Softwares/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
```

Comment: Finally set up the interpreter for your PyDev plugin. Lemme know in the comments, i will be checking this answer for rest of the day. I understand the fructration and hopefully folks at PyDev will address it soon.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm guessing there is some bug with pydev 3.0.0

Comment: uninstalled eclipse as i was unable to uninstall pydev and added the unzipped contents of the pydev plugin 2.8.2 in dropins folder of eclipse and it worked   Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Installing last version of the JRE (1.8) helped for Mars version. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

First things first, go to [pydev offcial page](http://www.pydev.org/), it stated:

> See: the **PyDev does not appear after install** section on the [download
>   page](http://www.pydev.org/download.html#pydev-does-not-appear-after-install) for help on using a Java 8 vm in Eclipse.

Visits [this page](http://www.pydev.org/download.html#pydev-does-not-appear-after-install), it shows:

> Well, the main issue at this time is that PyDev **requires Java 8** in
>   order to run. So, if you don't want to support PyDev by going the
>   LiClipse route (which is mostly a PyDev standalone plus some goodies),
>   you may have to go through some loops to make sure that you're
>   actually using Java 8 to run Eclipse/PyDev (as explained below).
>
> Also, keep in mind that PyDev 5.x requires Eclipse 4.6 onwards (for
>   Eclipse 3.8 use PyDev 4.x).

In my system:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_102"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-8u102-b14.1-2-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode)
```

According to [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/193652/125837)

> Java 8 (a.k.a 1.8)

So my **openJDK 1.8 is Java 8** already met the requirement stated from the pydev statement above. So **it's not Java problem in my case**.

Recall the pydev last statement:

> Also, keep in mind that PyDev 5.x requires Eclipse 4.6 onwards (for
>   Eclipse 3.8 use PyDev 4.x).

So I check my eclipse version, it's merely **old version 3.8.1**:

[image]

But what I've downloaded is **latest version pydev 5.3.0**, which is wrong, so now what I have to do is follow [this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175525/1074998) to uninstall pydev 5.3.0 first:

[image]

Use Shift key to highlight both and uninstall:

[image]

After uninstalled, visits [this page](http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/) to copy the old repo link:

[image]

Recall the pydev last statement again:

> Also, keep in mind that PyDev 5.x requires Eclipse 4.6 onwards (for
>   Eclipse 3.8 use PyDev 4.x).

My eclipse is 3.8.1, so I just have to choose 4.x. The highest version of 4.x listed above is 4.5.5.

I copy the link http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/4.5.5 and paste into eclipse's **Install New Software** page to install:

[image]

After all, Windows -> Preferences, pydev is showing up now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This procedure works with eclipse (from the official repository) on ubunutu-16.04.

Comment: This works for me.
I used Eclipse 4.2.2 Classic in Windows 8 and try to install PyDev 5.* but it ddnt work and then based on this comment PyDev 4.5.5 works for me

Thnx alot

Comment: Very Useful. Thank you. Worked for me.

Comment: Install java8 64bit (mine is 64bit eclipse) and set system path to that resolves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

1. Update your Java to [the latest SDK.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
2. Restart Eclipse.

PyDev will be shown in Eclipse>>Preferences

Answer (score 3):

update Java version. 
Install the new java. 
Go to Eclipse-> Preference-> Java -> Intalled JRE -> Check latest java (1.8) -> Apply. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem; it seems I was using Eclipse with Java 1.6 instead of with Java 1.7 as required by PyDev.

The fix, for PyDev 3.1.0 on Linux at least, is to start Eclipse with the Java 1.7 binary.  Two ways to do this: updating the default Java installation for the system to 1.7 or edit the eclipse.ini to point to a Java 1.7 java binary.

Comment: After you installed at least Java 1.7 an restarted, you might still need to go to the menu "Window">>"Customise Perspective" click on the "Comand group availability Tab"  and check all the PyDev components.
Then on the top right corner of eclipse, click on the "open perspective button" (the one with a plus sign next to "quick access" field) and add the PyDev Perspective.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu users:

Check for Java version (`$ java -version`). If it is 1.6.0, please upgrade it to 1.7.0 (`$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`)

Also, run the command `$ sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Restart Eclipse and Pydev will show up in the preferences.

Answer (score 2):

As per PyDev documentation states, the latest 5.x version now requires Java8 and Eclipse 4.5 onwards (http://www.pydev.org/)

You can use a 4.x PyDev version, which requires Java7, using the alternative update sites (http://www.pydev.org/update_sites/index.html)

Comment: The problem is that it is not mentioned when you install the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The [PyDev installation guide](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) addresses this issue. The solution is to update to Java 7 or later.

Edit: As @aaron-hall suggested, I'll give a more detailed explanation:

The nice folks that develop PyDev have decided to upgrade the Java version they are using (wise decision, but breaks compatibility backwards). If you have Java 6, then you need to upgrade at least to 7 (you can find numerous sites explaining how to do it in case you don't know). After you have installed the new version of Java, inside Eclipse go to Preferences/Java/Installed JREs and add your recently installed JRE. After that, restart Eclipse and install PyDev as you normally would. Everything should work fine now.

If for some reason you can't or won't install Java 7 or 8, then you must stick to PyDev 2.8.x.

Answer (score 1):

in my case, you need to use jdk 1.8, if the pydev is 5.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody has **Eclipse Neon**, this is how I fixed it:

1. From the **Window** menu > **Perspective** > **Customize**
2. Check **Pydev Debug** and the sub-items you're interested in.

Now you can see the **Pydev** on the Menu bar.

Comment: it works for me, the `PyDev Debug` action sets it not available by default, but you can let it work, thank you for all.

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to run `eclipse` from the command line with the `-clean` flag:

```
eclipse -clean
```

This has to be done once in a while around package upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

I went through all the above steps, but it didn't work. At last, I saw that my launcher pointed to a wrong Java installation. It was:

```
   eclipse -vm /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_67/bin/java
```

then I corrected to the java installation appropriate for my case, as stated in the previous answers, and it works:

```
   eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/bin/java
```

Of course these are my installation dependent paths. You should check your owns.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that has to be checked when installing pydev from install new software on eclipse.

1. Version of eclipse
2. Version of java

If you are using java 7 and still you cant find pydev under preferences(that happened to me), there is a good chance that you have installed a version of pydev which is above 4.5.5. PyDev 4.5.5 is the last release supporting Java 7 and Eclipse 3.8. For more details, go through this link http://www.pydev.org/ under release 5.2.0.
Like wise for java 6, an older version of pydev will help solve the issue, and there are a lot of sites which will find your right version of pydev according to your eclipse and java version
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. My environment looked like this

- Windows 7 Enterprise (64 bit)
- Eclipse SDK 4.2
- Python 3.6.1
- Pydev 5.2
- JRE 1.8.0_111

In the above configuration the PyDev plugin didn't show up.

I did the following:

- Installed the jdk 1.8 (64 bit)
- Installed Eclipse Neon
- Installed the Pydev plugin using the Plugin manager.

All works fine now !

It is clearly stated in the installation instructions that PyDev requires Java 8 and Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) in order to run and only supports Python 2.6 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while installing the plugin, I had forgotten to click on a checkbox to trust a certificate, then I installed it again, checked the checkbox and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem too, and I solved it just by waiting for eclipse to download all files, it takes some time.
When the downloads are completed eclipse will remind you to restart, if you see that remind you have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (setup by Oomph) into the folder 'C:\Program Files' with administrator privileges on Windows. After manually renaming/moving the Eclipse installation folder and installing PyDev, it did not show up as Perspective.

A possible solution is to run Eclipse as administrator and to reinstall PyDev.

Note: When the initial installation directory of Eclipse is not changed, PyDev also works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Solved with updating vm args. Just pointed to java8.

```
-vm E:/sw/java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/javaw.exe
```