# Removing a plugin for Webbrowsers (MyEclipse)

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

this little tool appears in every browser that im using for coding:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/St5eX.jpg

How can i get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: webclipse is extremely annoying nagging you in multiple ways (pop ups, code warnings in the editor, etc) to upgrade after a short trial and ultimately useless unless you upgrade. they should be banned for this practices.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the server connector you're using has CodeLive enabled. See [this article](https://www.genuitec.com/products/webclipse/learning-center/using-live-preview/) about using CodeLive. There are a couple of ways to enable/disable CodeLive for a particular server, mentioned in that article but one way is to use the context menu for the server in the Servers view (click to disable, click again to enable):

[image: servers view context menu]

Comment: Can I use codelive without using myeclipse that is in normal angular app?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean as CodeLive is part of MyEclipse but can be used for any server, including the Angular CLI servers. For purely Angular development, CodeLive is also in AngularIDE and Webclipse (both available from Genuitec).

Comment: As codeLive provide you the widget on browser to identify the compnents. I dont want to use (MyEclipse,WebEclipse(standalone and plugin of MyEclipse)) and AngularIDE. I have a simple angular project  created with angular-cli, how can I use CodeLive with this project?

Comment: Sorry but CodeLive is not available as a separate plug-in. It is only in those three products (MyEclipse, Webclipse and AngularIDE). If you don't want to pay, the Pro features of Webclipse and AngularIDE (including CodeLive) can be used for up to 8 days (not necessarily consecutive days) free each month.

Answer (score 0):

As the [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F) says :

Run **Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, select the software you no longer want and click Uninstall. (On Macintosh it is Eclipse > About Eclipse > Installation Details.)**

Bonus: [Correct way to remove plugin from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174725/correct-way-to-remove-plugin-from-eclipse)