# Eclipse suddenly won't launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm a regular Eclipse user and never had any problems with it what so ever (any serious ones at least, can't be a regular Eclipse user without having problems). So a few days ago I installed a library for c++ called Crypto++, the installation of the program had to do with some tweaks in the environment variables, which could somehow be related to my issue? 
Anyways here's the free first lines of the log:

```
!SESSION 2017-05-17 23:25:23.454 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

This is a continuation of log file C:\Users\user-pc\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
Created Time: 2017-05-17 23:26:06.159

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2017-05-17 23:26:06.163
!MESSAGE Exception occurred while rendering: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.impl.PlaceholderImpl@18d11527 (elementId: org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView, tags: [], contributorURI: null) (widget: null, renderer: org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer@2c6a6ce3, toBeRendered: true, onTop: false, visible: true, containerData: null, accessibilityPhrase: null) (closeable: false)
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument cannot be null
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4514)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4419)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.checkParent(Widget.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.<init>(Widget.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.<init>(Scrollable.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.<init>(Composite.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.createElement(PartServiceImpl.java:1257)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:401)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyShowView(WorkbenchPage.java:1278)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$12.run(WorkbenchPage.java:4316)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.showView(WorkbenchPage.java:4312)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin$1.run(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runTimer(Display.java:4329)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.messageProc(Display.java:3418)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2552)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 0 2017-05-17 23:26:32.789
!MESSAGE Invalid ZIP archive: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext\zipfs.jar

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2017-05-17 23:26:32.794
!MESSAGE Could not create Problems view

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2017-05-17 23:26:32.800
!MESSAGE Abnormal Workbench Condition

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-05-17 23:26:32.853
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.LinkageError: Error reading class bytes: org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock
```

Comment: Maybe try what this user did http://oohhyeah.blogspot.com/2013/10/error-starting-eclipse.html

Comment: You may have to reinstall Java, The `!MESSAGE Invalid ZIP archive: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\ext\zipfs.jar`. If java is not a problem, then try to find the lib: `Crypto++` on eclipse installation folder, remove it. [Like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174725/correct-way-to-remove-plugin-from-eclipse)