# Feature file not getting formatted in Cucumber format

Tags: eclipse, cucumber

In eclipse, for cucumber feature file using for selenium,

1. When a feature file was opened, the feature file used to show in cucumber/gherkin format which doesn't show anymore.
2. When a feature file is created, sample features used to be created
3. When a feature is executed using dry run, Step definitions used to be created.
4. src/test/java and src/test/resources are showing greyed out in eclipse which was not the case.

Above mentioned three things are not happening any more which used to work earlier. I believe it's related to the set up of eclipse. I know the issue, not sure what details might be required. So please do let me know what might be required so that I can share here.

**Eclipse Version:**

```
Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200
```

Answer (score 0):

That means either your editor is disable or corrupted.

1)

Try to open your feature file again as below:

[image]

Select other if cucmber editor not shown.

2)

Uninstall the cucumber plugin and install again.

Refer below link to uninstall the plugin from eclipse

[Correct way to remove plugin from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174725/correct-way-to-remove-plugin-from-eclipse)

Comment: I could change the default editor type to cucumber which solves one issue of opening feature file with Cucumber. But this doesn't solve the issue of generating the step definitions during dry run and src/test/java and src/test/resources are showing greyed out in eclipse which was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

1. When a feature file was opened, the feature file used to show in
   cucumber/gherkin format which doesn't show anymore.

> Changed the default editor to cucumber, Not sure how default editor
>   was changed

2. When a feature file is created, sample features used to be created

> After changing the default editor to cucumber, this started working

3. When a feature is executed using dry run, Step definitions used to
       be created.

> Added this parameter in the

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty","summary"})
```

4. src/test/java and src/test/resources are showing greyed out in
       eclipse which was not the case.

> ```
> Not sure, but this is not creating any issues so far
> ```

Answer (score 0):

[Associating feature file type with cucumber in Selenium WebDriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzdQQ.png)

I don't know the reason but I am also having a similar problem occasionally. When you over the file name go to the file tab and choose properties and then choose Associate with File Type --> then choose cucumber. I hope it helps.